# Loop and Return HTML in Javascript (Template Literals)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I'm creating a chat module. Everything's done but I use a too modern code for IE10/IE11 and I need this compatibility ...

I changed a lot of things but I'm stuck with something easy for you guyz I'm sure.

I need to go back from a template literal to an old way. Any Help ? Here's my function I need to change : `data` is a simple Array with Objects in it : `data = [{},{},{}]`

```
function createChatBox(data) {
        return ` <div class="vchat__options">
            ${data.map((info, index) =>
                `${info.action === 'site' ? `<a href="${info.url}" target="_blank" id="vchat__${index}" class="vchat__box">
                <div class="vchat__block">
                    ${info.svg}
                    <p class="vchat__text"><strong class="vchat__headline">${info.headline}</strong>${info.text}</p>
                    <span class="vchat__highlight">${info.highlight}${info.highlight_icono}</span>
                </div>
                </a>` : `<div id="vchat__${info.id}" class="vchat__box ${info.action === 'next' ? 'js-vchatPanel' : 'js-vchatZopim'}">
                <div class="vchat__block">
                    ${info.svg}
                    <p class="vchat__text"><strong class="vchat__headline">${info.headline}</strong>${info.text}</p>
                    <span class="vchat__highlight">${info.highlight}${info.highlight_icono}</span>
                </div>
                </div>`}`
            ).join('')}
        </div>`;
    }
```

I don't need the full code. Just any tips, advices will be cool !
Thank you

Comment: Hi @Clement, can you elaborate on what is the problem you are facing? That will help the community to get back to you with an appropriate answer. :-)

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). This is far too broad for SO's Q&A format. Just use any of several templating libraries.

Comment: @LloydFrancis my issue is that the "template literal" is not OK with IE10/IE11 and I have nothing yet to make it compatible (Babel, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to transpile new ES6 JavaScript syntax to be compatible with older browsers. Once setup, you can specify which browser versions etc. you need to support.

Put your code example into the [online Babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) to view results.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to see my code in this old fashion way !! Don't know why I didn't think about that. Thank you !